# Shell Script and Command Line Discrepancies

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I was wondering if there were specific permissions that were associated with a shell script or if some variable references are taken as being syntactically different.

I tried my short renaming script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Renaming Script" 

for file in ./*
do
rename=$(echo $file | sed 's/\(img_\)\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)_\([0-9]*\).jpg/newyears_20\3-\2_0\4.jpg/')
mv $file $rename
done
```

All it does is rename a few files, but I noticed that it would work on the command line, but not in the shell script when I ran `sh rename.sh`

I got the error

```
rename.sh: syntax error at line 7: `rename=$' unexpected
```

Is variable assignment handled differently in the shell than on the command line?

Comment: Since this is a bash script, you should run it as `bash rename.sh`.

Comment: On what kind of *nix system are you running this shell script? I have been using Linux systems for 9 years. All the shell script has had to have is #!/bin/bash at the top line (really #!/bin/sh on those systems where /bin/sh was a soft link to /bin/bash), and on Ubuntu/Debian #!/bin/bash is necessary. And, the shell script needs to be protected for execute. I usually do chmod 775 to allow user and group modification privs and non-group execute privs.  Not that it's invalid, I've never had to run a script with bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different shells handle commands differently.  Your script is a `bash` script (as identified on the first line `#!/bin/bash`), therefore it needs to be run by `bash`, not `sh`.

```
bash rename.sh
```

Comment: Curious, since the script identifies bash in the first line, would this be equivalent to running `./rename.sh` (which is how I usually execute bash scripts)?

Comment: I'm not sure there's any reason to go `bash rename.sh`.  Like you, I would just go `./rename.sh`.  But if you do choose to specify which shell to use, then you'd better be using the syntax that shell understands.